# Tabla dinámica usando puro codigo - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla en Android Studio, pero quiero saber como hacerla a través de puro código, sin tanta necesidad de usar el .xml y saber como manejar sus propiedades.

Ya que la tabla se creara según la cantidad de datos que se traiga de un arreglo.

 Las cabeceras son fijas, pero la cantidad de registros no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de esta manera: primero agregas la tabla a tu fragment o actividad:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"/>
```

y obtienes su referencia, por ejemplo, de esta manera

```
TableLayout grid = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

Después, por cada registro que vas a agregarle deberías "inflar" la fila de la tabla

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ao_detail_line, null);
```

en ese caso estoy inflando una TableRow llamado "ao_detail_line", que tiene dos TextView (donde voy a poner mis datos)

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>
```

Luego establezco el valor de cada TextView (o sea, cada columna de mi tabla) y agrego el TableRow a mi tabla

```
((TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.lTitle)).setText(.....); //Dato de la columna 1
((TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.lDetail)).setText(.....); //Dato de la columna 2
grid.addView(tr);
```

Y eso es todo.  En tu caso deberías modificar el XML del layout del TableRow para que tenga los TextView o elementos que necesites por cada fila, y luego asignar los valores de estos elementos por cada fila.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!